# Uniquely identify programatically a device on iOS 7 and later

Tags: ios, ios7, uuid, imei

In my Android app I am identifying a device and a SIM card reading the IMEI and IMSI respectively.

How can I do it programmatically on iOS 7 and later? I see that the UUID identifies the app + device, and it changes every time you reinstall it, so it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: @jcesarmobile on delete & reinstall it changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no FIXED (publicly available) ID anymore. UUID is off limits and using the mac address isn't fixed

`identifierForVendor` changes on reinstall but thats all you have :)

---

EXCEPT if you want / can argue you do advertising. Then you can checkout the `advertisingIdentifier` [dont try to abuse it though!]

Comment: It is documented to change